# How does PSR-4 autoloading work in composer for custom libraries?

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-4

I use the following directory structure based on my understanding of how namespaces in PHP work:

```
project_root
    app/
    |    lib/
    |    |    MyCompany/
    |    |    |    Utility/
    |    |    |    |    Logger.php
    |    |    |    Core/
    |    |    |    |    User.php
vendor/
    composer/
    symfony/
    guzzle/
bootstrap.php
composer.json
```

According to the PSR-4 specification, a fully qualified class name has the following form:

```
\<NamespaceName>(\<SubNamespaceNames>)*\<ClassName>
```

**Question 1:**

From my directory structure above, is the assumption below correct?

- NamespaceName = MyCompany
- SubNamespaceNames = Utility | Core
- ClassName = Logger | User

**Question 2:**

If my bootstrap.php file contains the following:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

How would I [configure the 'autoload'](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4) section of composer.json to autoload the classes in the MyCompany directory? Such that I would be able to create an instance of Logger in bootstrap.php

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Taken from the documentation you linked:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyCompany\\": "app/lib/MyCompany/",
        }
    }
}
```

This is pretty self explanatory, it simply tells the autoloader that `app/lib/MyCompany` is the root for the `MyCompany\` namespace.

You would then be able to use the class as `\MyCompany\Utility\Logger`.

Note that in PSR-4, unlike PSR-0, you'd normally omit `MyCompany` from the directory structure, and just use `app/lib/`.

Comment: You will also need to run `composer dump-autoload` once you've added this snippet in order for it to work.