# What rule does composer use for autoloading custom classes?

Tags: model-view-controller, composer-php, autoload, classname

I have been learning to use composer for some time. And for the first time, I have moved my code to production server. Many of the issues experienced by other first time users, namely autoloading, happened. In my case, it turned out to be that the file names were the culprits. Compose expected certain file names to follow the class name.

I noticed that abstract classes were among those. Others were those classes with compound names like ClassName as against Name. However what confuses me is that in some cases, things worked without changing anything while in others, composer forced me to change the file names.

To be specific, I am using my own MVC and the base class Controller had to be changed along with others in the models folder.

I have done `$loader = require "vendor/autoload.php";`

```
`$loader->add("", ["my folders"])`
```

Everything I have tested so far now seems to be OK. But I fear something might go wrong later, since I can't predict all that a user on the site might do. I need help, anyone. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to follow PSR-4 standard, which means editing only `composer.json`. You don't need to add `$loader->add("", ["my folders"])`.

**composer.json**

```
"autoload": {
    "*": "/dirs"
}
```

But it's better to be specific, like:

```
"autoload": {
    "App\": "app"
}
```

(It's like "namespace": "directory to be found in".)

Then having `App\Controller\PageController` class in `app/Controller/PageController.php` file.

---

You may also find similar questions => answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27802507/1348344) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28607674/psr-4-autoloading-with-composer)

Comment: What happens to classes that are not namespaced, how do I use PSR-4 for those? Just curious.

Comment: You should namespace every class. That's purpose of PSR-0 and PSR-4.